# CSS - UL LI navigation with display:table-cell and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, opera

I have an issue with my menu in IE9-10. In any other browser spaces between elements are equals. But In IE it displays fixed width for each item. The behavior will be the same in other browsers if I will specify `table-layout:fixed` to `<nav>` tag, but I tryed to specify `table-layout:auto` with no success.

Here is Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UcuBt/

Is there any way to fix it? Thanks

**UPDATED**
The same issue in Opera 12.15

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width:1%;` for `table-cell` item, then in IE they will take space needed and won't be even cells anymore.

if that was your problem :)

Comment: I tryed to remove it but instead of fixed width I got the other problem - items collapsing. You can see that the way it will display them is different from other browser's

Comment: too bad, CC are not avalaible for IE10 !

Comment: You could try, display:table with CC for IE9 and lower and display:flex including prefixe for IE10 ...

Comment: conditionnal Comment, that filters IE's version untill 9 . http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/